# Chain goes slack in gear 5-10 and very noisey hum

Tags: derailleur-rear, noise

When I’m coasting downhill  >35 kph and chain is in gears 5-10 and I hit a bump the chain goes slack, a very loud irritating hum/vibration sound is emitted from the rear wheel until either I pedal or shift into any gears 1-4? Chain & cassette is brand new. I’ve checked the cassette is tight enough.

Comment: What do you mean by gears 5-10? What kind of bike is this and what kind of drivetrain is on it?